# Is the level of play impacted when a GM plays blindfolded?

Tags: blindfold-chess

Since my last question was closed before I got an answer I try again (hoping it won't get closed this time): When I look at a game of professional player on the internet, very often they don't even look at the chess board when they are thinking about the position. So I was wondering, does it change anything to play blindfolded for, say, a grandmaster ? In other word, is their level of play impacted when they play like this ?